# What are the click button and link command for PHPUnit Selenium?

Tags: phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I am writing test with the selenium and I export to phpunit.
But click command doesn't work for me. I am writing like that `$this->click("css=input.login");`. But it shows errors like that `ERROR: Command execution failure`. And I already tested mine element correct or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can find it from [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/IDYUvv3hKJI). And the answer is the following.

This might also be related to a Selenium bug with the recent Firefox release (FF 22 I think), see (will be fixed in Selenium 2.34).

See Details in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/IDYUvv3hKJI).